# updatedb to whitelist a branch of a blacklisted directory tree

Tags: linux, directory, whitelist, locate

Well PRUNEPATHS in updatedb blacklists directories. My situation is that I have a directory with many subdirectories:

```
/A/a1
/A/a2
/A/a3
/A/a4
/A/a5
/A/a6
/A/a7
/A/a8
/A/a9
...
/A/aN
/A/whitelisted_directory
```

Note that the useless folders cannot be matched by a regex and are added/removed all the time.
Is there a way to tell updatedb to look in /A/whitelisted_directory  but not the rest in /A/?
Thank you in advance!